notion public integration API
I have problem about notion public integration API when I create page like this code:
def create_notion_page(access_token, duplicated_template_id,database_id):
    url = "https://api.notion.com/v1/pages"
    headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Notion-Version": "2022-06-28" 
    }
    data = {
        "parent": {
            "type": "page_id",
            "page_id": duplicated_template_id
        },
        "properties": {
            "title": [
                {
                    "text": {
                        "content": "Flashcards Page ID and Database ID"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "children": [
            {
                "object": "block",
                "type": "paragraph",
                "paragraph": {
                    "rich_text": [
                        {
                            "type": "text",
                            "text": {
                                "content": "Please keep this info private. If others get it, they can modify your Notion Flashcards."
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "object": "block",
                "type": "paragraph",
                "paragraph": {
                    "rich_text": [
                        {
                            "type": "text",
                            "text": {
                                "content": f"Flashcards Page ID: {duplicated_template_id}"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "object": "block",
                "type": "paragraph",
                "paragraph": {
                    "rich_text": [
                        {
                            "type": "text",
                            "text": {
                                "content": f"Database ID: {database_id}"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=data)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        print("Page created successfully!")
    else:
        print(f"Error creating page: {response.text}")

It works well,
but went I try to add information in the same page with this code:
import requests

def add_row_to_notion_database(access_token, database_id,properties):
    url = f"https://api.notion.com/v1/pages/"
    headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Notion-Version": "2022-06-28"
    }
    data = {
        "parent": {
            "type": "database_id",
            "database_id": database_id
        },
        "properties": properties
    }
    print(data)
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=data)

    if response.status_code == 200 or response.status_code == 201:
        print("Row added successfully!")
        return response.json()
    else:
        print(f"Error adding row: {response.text}")
        return response.json()

I got this error:

Error adding row:
{"object":"error","status":404,"code":"object_not_found","message":"Could not find database with ID: 583adfba-e506-43a8-b059-47f9c2d63a06. Make sure the relevant pages and databases are shared with your integration.","request_id":"4269100f-74d3-4b2a-8701-17b49ec9d43c"}

It is the same page that should be shared with the integration because I can add the page from the code above.
I tried to add data to the database in my Notion using a public API integration that I developed, but it returned an error.
